# How to use RL algorithm on flow?

Tags: flow-project

I want to use RL algorithm to train my project. But I cannot find that on flow directory, how many types of algorithms I could use, and there are some explain document of these algorithms, or If I want to create a custom algorithm, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've installed rllib to start training with Flow. If you go to the `agents` directory located under `Ray/ray/python/ray/rllib/agents/` you can find the supported algorithms such as PPO and DDPG.

Comment: yes, I find this directory, but it is not under flow directory, it is ok?

Comment: Yes that shouldn't be an issue, train away!